# How can I restrict the images selectable by the user in Wagtail's ImageChooserBlock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Some image content on my Wagtail site must meet certain requirements (e.g. a differing minimum size for banner images, carousel images, etc.).

I know I can validate my image requirements after the edit form data is submitted, but I'd like to make the workflow more user-friendly by restricting the widget to only show images that will pass validation in the first place. What is the best way to go about this?

Wagtail 5.2.2